# Shopify Liquid - how to show content based on dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

On my Shopify store I want to show an HTML banner in a liquid file from 02/01/2022 - 02/14/2022. It's only for Valentines day orders so I want to auto show the banner just on those dates from the 1st to the 14th.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Spotify liquid documentation, you can create a conditional code path using the code snippet below:

```
{% assign start = "2022-01-02" | date: '%s' %}
{% assign end = "2022-02-14" | date: '%s' %}
{% assign today = "now" | date: '%s' %}
{% if  start <= today and today <= end %}
    <h2>Show banner</h2>
{% endif %}
```

This code will only show the banner within the specified timeframes. You can try it out on the Liquid editor here: https://liquidjs.com/playground.html

Comment: If i wanted this code to do every year at same time but don't want to go into code and update the year like 2022 to 2023, how can this be achieved, with something like this?

`{% assign year = 'now' | date: '%Y' %}
{% assign start = "01-02" | date: '%s' %}
{% assign end = "02-25" | date: '%s' %}
{% assign today = "now" | date: '%s' %}
{% if  start <= today and today <= end %}
    <h2>Show banner</h2>
{% else %}<br/>
    <h2>Nothing</h2>
{% endif %}`

Comment: Incase someone else needs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71258952/shopify-liquid-display-banner-within-certain-dates/71263919#71263919

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple if-statement. With `Date()` you get all info that you need.

```js
const date = new Date();

if (date.getDate() > 14 && date.getMonth() === 1 && date.getFullYear() === 2022) {
    document.getElementById('banner').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">BANNER</div>
```

Ensure that `date.getMonth()` is set to 1 for February, since values start with 0.

Comment: I add this into the page and its showing the banner content regardless of what date it set too. Also I need it to only show from 2/1/22 - 2/14/22, any chance we can get it to do that?

Comment: @aBe it should be `date.getDate() > 14` and not `date.getDate() <= 14`. I have edited my answer. In the following example, you will see the banner until 01/15/2022: https://jsfiddle.net/rf8qn6ks/